# How to close the Android keyboard when switching activities/tabs

Tags: android, keyboard, android-activity

I have created a method to check if the keyboard is used in an activity(tab) with the editText: searchfield. Whenever I leave the activity(tab) and switches to another one, I want to close the keyboard. Therefor I call the method in onStop(). But nothing happens, why is this not working, anyone with more insights on how onStop() works in Android? How can I make it work? /Thanx alot!

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    this.hideKeyboard();  <----------------------
    if(this.data != null)
    {
        this.data.destroy();
    }
}

private void hideKeyboard()
{
    if (this.searchField != null)
    {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.searchField.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `onPause()` instead of `onStop()`?

Comment: Try using `TabHost.OnTabChangeListener()` in your main `Activity` and call your `hideKeyboard()` method from there. `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html

Comment: onPause solved the problem, thanx alot guys! / Happy :)

Comment: @JesperMartensson : Be aware that the appearance of a `Dialog` (for example) will cause the current `Activity` to be paused, i.e., `onPause()` will be called. If your code design won't be affected by such a situation then that's fine - your question does specify changing tabs, however, and the `onTabChangeListener` approach is the correct way to go in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*From Comment*

`onStop()` won't be called when you switch the Tab. Use `onPause()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You probably should do it in `onPause()` instead of `onDestroy()` beause usually switching to a new Activity won't finish the current one unless you explicitly do it.